# slow PreRequestHandlerExecute in post actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have an asp.net mvc 3 application running on IIS 7. The problem is that sometimes the PreRequestHandlerExecute function takes too much time to finish running when doing post actions.

- I do not run any code in the event.
- This happens only on post actions.
- It does not happens in all post request, but only in some of them.
- I run on Windows Server Web 2008, 8GB memory and 4 cpus.

I read in another post that adjusting the machine.config processModel section might solve this. Here is my processModel node:

```
<processModel 
enable="true" 
timeout="Infinite" 
idleTimeout="Infinite" 
shutdownTimeout="00:00:05" 
requestLimit="Infinite" 
requestQueueLimit="5000" 
restartQueueLimit="10" 
memoryLimit="70" 
webGarden="false" 
cpuMask="0xffffffff" 
userName="machine" 
password="AutoGenerate" 
logLevel="Errors" 
clientConnectedCheck="00:00:05" 
comAuthenticationLevel="Connect" 
comImpersonationLevel="Impersonate" 
responseDeadlockInterval="00:03:00" 
responseRestartDeadlockInterval="00:03:00" 
autoConfig="false" 
maxWorkerThreads="100" 
maxIoThreads="100" 
minWorkerThreads="20" 
minIoThreads="20" 
serverErrorMessageFile="" 
pingFrequency="Infinite" 
pingTimeout="Infinite" 
maxAppDomains="2000" />
```

But still this did not solved the latency.
Does any one has an idea?